# Bending an image

Tags: iphone, image-processing, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I want to bend a rod like image in response to user touches. The user should be able  to change the curvature of the image using touches. How do you do this using Quartz? There is obviously no standard transform for this. I am having a tough time figuring the math for doing this.

Comment: 1. Does it have to be an image? 2. Does it have to be Quartz?

Comment: Yes. It does have to be an image. If this can be done with Quartz, it would be great, but i am not sure if this can be done by Quartz. Do I need to use OpenGL for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do it using just an affine transform, which is by definition linear. You can draw the bar in many small chunks, slowly bending along the path, or use OpenGL to draw them along a tri-strip or quad-strip.